# extract numbers from json with logstash and send to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to parse a json log containing numbers, although represented as strings e.g.

> {"metric":"123"}

and I have tens of such metric values.
Is there any way to configure the json filter to interpret all fields as numbers? or any way to mutate them without having to specify every single one of them?
In parallel I'm trying to have the source of such message send a number in the json instead, e.g.

> {"metric":123}

which does show up on elasticsearch as a number field, but this may become harder than making this change in logstash if possible.

any suggestions?

Comment: If you create your ES mapping beforehand and specify that `metric` should be an `integer` you can still send `"123"` and ES will try to coerce that to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed as Val said the index mapping can be created beforehand, sorry for such a fundamental question.
More info here https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash_lesson_elasticsearch_mapping